# How can I send send() and recv() on the same socket in a loop?

Tags: c, loops, sockets, input

I am trying to create an IRC client for Freenode

My code is as such:

```
 while ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFFSIZE -1, 0)) != -1) {

        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("client: %s\n", buf);

        if (strstr(buf, "Nickname is already in use"))
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        if (strstr(buf, "PING")) {
            num_bytes_sent = send(sockfd, "PONG", 5, 0);
            printf("%d PONG\n", num_bytes_sent);
        }        
}
```

I want to be able to use `send()` for user input using `scanf()`, but I cannot use `scanf()` inside the loop because it stops the socket from receiving data until `scanf()` receives input. Is there any way the loop can continue to receive data without stopping to wait for user input?

Comment: You need to check if there is input available, and read that much (and be prepared for the possibility that the input is not complete). Or use non-blocking I/O. Either option typically means reading into a buffer instead of being able to use `fscanf` or similar directly.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  Data will arrive at your socket whether you call `recv()` or not, so if you want to block at user input nothing's stopping you from doing that, then receiving from your socket later. Of course, eventually you risk the socket's buffers filling up.  If you want to check for user input while also checking for data available on a socket you can use some sort of [select / poll](https://notes.shichao.io/unp/ch6/) loop.

Comment: basically I have a scanf() in my while loop, which means I cannot recv until I am done inputting something. but I want to be able to continuously receive and only optionally input (like a chat)

Comment: That's what functions like [`select()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)) and its cousins `poll()` and `epoll()`, among others, are for.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) system call. Here is an example of its use (using `write` and `read` instead of `send` and `recv` though):

```
fd_set fds_receive;    // set of file descriptors
char buffer[BUFSIZE];

FD_ZERO(&fds_receive); // initialize the set

while (1) {

        FD_SET(socket_fd, fds_receive);  // monitor the socket
        FD_SET(STDIN_FD, fds_receive);   // monitor stdin

        /* the select system call will return when one of the file
        descriptors that it is monitoring is ready for an I/O operation */
        if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &fds_receive, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("select");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // if new data arrives from stdin
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FD, &fds_receive)) {
            num_bytes = read(STDIN_FD, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            if (num_bytes < 0) {          // error in the "read" system call
                perror("read");
                exit(-1);
            } else if (num_bytes == 0) {  // "Ctrl+D" pressed, stdin receives 0 bytes
                if (close(socket_fd) < 0) {
                    perror("close");
                    exit(-1);
                }

                exit(0);
            }

            // send data received in stdin to socket
            buffer[num_bytes] = '\0';
            if (write(socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1) < 0) {
                perror("write");
                exit(-1);
            }

        } 

        // if new data arrives from the socket
        if (FD_ISSET(socket_fd, &fds_receive)) {
            num_bytes = read(socket_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            if (num_bytes < 0) {         // error in the "write" system call
                perror("read");
                exit(-1);
            } else if (num_bytes == 0) { // connection terminated, no problem
                close(socket_fd);
                exit(0);
            }

            // do stuff with data that arrived from the socket
        }
    }
```

The `select` system call allows you to monitor multiple file descriptors. In this case, if you want to monitor both `stdin` and a socket, you put them on a set of file descriptors. The comments in the code should be helpful in understanding how it works. Cheers!